# aws Lambda Deployment automation using git,codepipeline,codebuild and cloudformation

Tags: continuous-integration, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am Creating CI/CD pipeline for lambda deployment,i am using Git->Codebuild-> aws cloudfromation->lambda using codepipline ,even after successful build my buildspec.yaml not able to generate proper samTemplate containing proper CodeUri and i am getting error 
*Unable to upload artifact ./ referenced by CodeUri parameter of HelloFunction resource.
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied*

this is my buildspec.yaml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
post_build:
commands:
  - echo Build completed on `date`
  - mvn clean package
  - aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket 
   <bucketname> --output-template NewSamTemplate.yaml

artifacts:
type: jar
files:
 - NewSamTemplate.yaml
```

and this is my samTemplate.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Helle world function
Resources:
HelloFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  Handler: 'com.example.lambda.demo.Hello::handleRequest'
  Runtime: java8
  CodeUri: ./
  Events:
    MyJavaApi:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /HelloWorld
        Method: GET
```

Comment: Looks like the Codebuild role you have doesn't have access to that bucket. Could you paste in the question the policies associated with that role ?

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard thanks for your reply,I have attached the policy and now its working fine.